# Error al hacer 'Build and Run the scheme' en xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Estoy teniendo problemas al hacer 'Build and Run the scheme' en **xcode** para pasar el proyecto a un dispositivo IPhone 4s y probar lo que estoy desarrollando, de un día para otro ha dejado de funcionar y no he tocado nada de la configuración del proyecto.

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> Code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK
>   'iOS 10.1'

Si necesitas algún detalle más no duden en pedírmelo, soy nuevo en el desarrollo de [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) y estoy en un proyecto hecho por otras personas que ya no están en la empresa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De primeras te diría que iOS 10 no es compatible con un iPhone 4s, ya que sólo se puede actualizar a iOS 10 los teléfonos desde el iPhone 5s[image: dispositivos compatibles]

En cualquier caso, necesitas configurar el firmado de la aplicación con un certificado, y configurarle el provisioning profile adecuado.

Puedes revisar estos 2 enlaces para ver como hacerlo:

- [Configuring Your Xcode Project for Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)
- [Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya he conseguido arreglarlo, el problema estaba en que habia expirado la sesión del appleID que había puesto, he tenido que volver a iniciar la sesión y además para  el Target de test he tenigo que seleccionar un Team para Signing